# what is the validity of session & token in tokbox?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opentok, tokbox

I have integrated tokbox in my app for live call, signaling.

My problem is session & token expire at every 1 hour. So is this valid?

What is the validity(time limit) of any session & token?

How to solve this problem

please guide us.

thank you.

Comment: In openTok session never expire. and you can set token expiration time from server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenTok sessions do not expire. However, authentication tokens do expire. Also, note that sessions cannot explicitly be destroyed.

OpenTok tokens expire after a set period of time (max up to 30 days). You can specify the expiration period when you generate the token. Read this https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-token/

While working on a test version of your app, you can obtain a test session ID and token using the Dashboard page. But every production OpenTok application should be generating these values dynamically on a server, using one of their many Server SDKs (PHP, node, Ruby, Python, .NET, Java)